# How can I use MySQL variable with POINT

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a MySQL variable together with POINT like this (simplified):

```
SET @lat=145.033667; SET @long=-37.932000; INSERT INTO Location(position) values (GeomFromText(‘POINT(@lat @long)'));
```

This works fine:

```
SELECT 'POINT(145.033667 -37.932000)';
```

As does this:

```
SELECT GeomFromText('POINT(145.033667 -37.932000)');
```

Is there anyone who know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error:

```
SET @lat=145.033667; 
SET @long=-37.932000; 
INSERT INTO Location(position) 
values (GeomFromText('POINT(@lat @long)'));  
                    ^^^ Here you need '
```

Comment: Why the minus?  
  
Try this, it is using the variable name as a string...  
    mysql>SET @lat=145.033667; SET @long=-37.932000; select 'POINT(@lat @long)';  
    +-------------------+  
    | POINT(@lat @long) |  
    +-------------------+  
    | POINT(@lat @long) |  
    +-------------------+  
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @Gustaf:- Yes you dont need it. Updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: It still doesn't solve that it is treating the variabels as part of the string.